# wlan0: [AP] denied authentication (status 17) on public network

Tags: wifi

I often have trouble connecting to my local library's WiFi on my laptop (a ThinkPad running Ubuntu MATE 16.10). This is a public network with no password required to get an address. I use `ifscheme` to switch WiFi profiles; here's the relevant block in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface wlan0-dnong inet dhcp
wireless-essid Library
```

But when I try to connect, I get no address, no association, and this line in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
wlan0: [AP MAC address] denied authentication (status 17)
```

I get no problems on Android phones.
The library staff are unhelpful - they don't know anything without a GUI and can't even escalate to someone who might.

I've been unable to find out even what status 17 is through Googling. I've tried restarting the systemd networking service, toggling the rfkill switch and fully rebooting, but none of those now allow me to connect (previously I could connect after doing some of those). It is possible it is related to which AP I am nearest to, but I don't have a lot of control over that.

I get that it's nearly impossible to give me a full solution with so many unknowns, but even a pointer of what to look for would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Please check, e.g. with `iw wlan0 scan` what exactly the AP requires. If it doesn't use WPA (with empty password, or whatever), you can manually connect with `iw connect`, see `iw help` for details. Try this and see what happens. That may collide with network manager or other programs that try to control your WLAN, but assume you don't run network manager if you are using `ifscheme`?

Comment: @dirkt Correct, I removed NetworkManager. It has caused me issues with gaming, especially in Wine. Unfortunately I won't be at that library again until Thursday, but I'll try then (hopefully I will remember that long). Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @dirkt It worked! It had no problems this way. I manually ran `sudo dhclient wlan0` to get an address after verifying with `iwconfig` that I was associated. Next question: do I have to do this every time, or can I use `ifupdown` to do it automatically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ifscheme`, and I don't how how it handles this. `ifupdown` *should* already do it automatically with the `dhcp` stanza in `interfaces`. The next thing I'd do in your place is try to find out why it doesn't work automatically in the first place. Possible some `systemd`/`ifscheme` interaction. Renaming commands and replacing them with shell scripts that log arguments, then call the original command helps a lot with debugging these issues.